# Is there a reason, not to make AbpUsers.tenantId a foreignKey?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I was querying against SQL Server to get all columns, that are referenced to other columns. By accident I saw, that the column "tenantId" (table "AbpUsers") is not referenced to AbpTenants.Id.

I asked some of my collegues, that are "used" to know aspnetboilerplate, just to clarify. Everyone was surprised, as I am.

Just for testing purposes I created a new database by "Update-database". Before running the application, I added the "missing" foreign-Key-reference manually. And? Nothing happened. Nothing bad happened. Everything works, as it did without the foreign-key-reference...

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AbpUsers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AbpUsers_AbpTenants_TenantId] FOREIGN KEY([TenantId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AbpTenants] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AbpUsers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AbpUsers_AbpTenants_TenantId]
GO
```

As expected my whole application works fine, even when the initial content builder is running.

Comment: Answered in [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-forsaken#409 (comment)](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-forsaken/issues/409#issuecomment-320175298).

Comment: @aaron: Thanks. Even if I was hoping to get another answer... :-)

Comment: Answer #409 above doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me either: if it is a foreign key, then this important table relationship should be marked as such in the DB to enable the DB and tools to work effectively outside of the app/framework itself.

Comment: my opinion. For the sake of completeness: my colleague had posted pretty much this argument also in this #409: the answer came quite soon and is at least useful ...

Answer (score 0):

Keys exist mainly to protect referential integrity of the database. If you have no Cascade Update or Cascade Delete options on, then maybe this key was removed to make deleting things easier for someone who did not know what they were doing.